# Type mismatch error when importing the value of a cell to use for an array for text to column delimitation

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub MyArray_Work()

Dim TextToColumnsValues() As Variant, i As Integer, MyNum As Integer, NumRow As Integer

NumRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


ReDim TextToColumnsValues(NumRow)

For i = 1 To NumRow

   MyNum = Range("B" & i).Value

   TextToColumnsValues(i) = Array(MyNum, 2)

Next

Debug.Print TextToColumnsValues(6)



Columns("C:C").Select

    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("C1"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        FieldInfo:=TextToColumnsValues, TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Comment: when it errors, what is the value in the cell in column B that is being assigned to `MyNum`?

Comment: What do you expect from `Array(MyNum, 2)`. You probably want to use `Array(i, 2)`, to set the text format. And `Debug.Print TextToColumnsValues(6)` does not make sense. How to print an array? Trying `Debug.Print TextToColumnsValues(6)(0)` can return something...

Comment: The value I expect to be assigned to MyNum is a number from my cell value. my goal is to automate a text to column delimitation based on numbers provided

Comment: Then, you should place `MyNum` as the second array element: `Array(i, MyNum`, where `i` should be the the column number = the iteration (row) number...

Comment: Let's say we ignore the Debug.Print statement. That was just for checking that my values were being stored. when you record a macro using text to column delimination normally it looks like this for the following spacers 0,6,17,3,1,1 Array(Array(0,1), Array(6,1), Array(23,1), Array(26,1), Array(27,1) etc.... what I'm trying to do is pull these numbers (0,6,23,26 etc..) which I already populated in Excel and feed it to the text to column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Apply `TextToColumns` Using Data From Column

- The Field argument requires a 1D array holding two-element 1D arrays, an array of arrays (jagged array).

```vb
Sub MyArray_Work()
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    Const sFirstCellAddress As String = "B2"
    Const dFirstCellAddress As String = "C2"
    Const ttcFormatNumber As Long = 2 ' Text or 1 - General, 4 - Date, 9 - Skip
    
    ' Reference the worksheet.
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    ' Reference the source range.
    
    Dim srg As Range
    Dim srCount As Long
    
    With ws.Range(sFirstCellAddress)
        Dim sLastRow As Long
        sLastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row
        srCount = sLastRow - .Row + 1
        If srCount < 1 Then Exit Sub
        Set srg = .Resize(srCount)
    End With

    ' Reference the destination range.
 
    Dim drg As Range
    
    With ws.Range(dFirstCellAddress)
        Dim dLastRow As Long
        dLastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row
        Dim drCount As Long: drCount = dLastRow - .Row + 1
        If drCount < 1 Then Exit Sub
        Set drg = .Resize(drCount)
    End With

    ' Write the values from the source range to the source array.
    
    Dim sData() As Variant
    
    If srCount = 1 Then ' one-cell
        ReDim sData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): sData(1, 1) = srg.Value
    Else ' multiple cells
        sData = srg.Value
    End If

    ' Define the destination arrays.
    
    Dim ttcColumnData() As Variant: ReDim ttcColumnData(1 To srCount)
    Dim ttcSingleData() As Variant: ReDim ttcSingleData(1 To 2)
    ttcSingleData(2) = ttcFormatNumber
        
    ' Write the values from the source array
    ' to the destination array of arrays.
        
    Dim sr As Long
    
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        ttcSingleData(1) = sData(sr, 1)
        ttcColumnData(sr) = ttcSingleData ' array to element
    Next sr
 
    ' Use the destination array to apply 'TextToColumns'
    ' on the destination range. 
    
    drg.TextToColumns Destination:=drg, DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        FieldInfo:=ttcColumnData, TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

    ' Inform.

    MsgBox "Data parsed.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

**The Dialog**

- If there is already data in the columns next to the first column, a dialog with the following message will appear:

> There's already data here. Do you want to replace it?

- If you select `Yes`, you will overwrite the data.
- But if you select `Cancel`, the following error will occur:

> Run-time error '1004': Unable to get the TextToColumns property of the
> Range class.

- To overwrite without the dialog appearing, you could use the following:

  ```
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
      drg.TextToColumns Destination:=drg, DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
          FieldInfo:=ttcColumnData, TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
  ```
- To let the dialog appear but avoid the error occurring, you could use something like this:

  ```
  Dim ttc As Variant:
  On Error Resume Next
      ttc = drg.TextToColumns( _
          Destination:=drg, DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
          FieldInfo:=ttcColumnData, TrailingMinusNumbers:=True)
  On Error GoTo 0

  ' Inform.

  If ttc Then ' True
      MsgBox "Data parsed.", vbInformation
  Else ' Empty, due to the error
      MsgBox "Data not parsed.", vbExclamation
  End If
  ```